# javascript run lines after a line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using canvas and javascript to increase the height, transform and rotate and canvas but it seems like all three processes are done at the same time. Is there any how I can first increase the height then rotate and transform?

Here is my code:

```
ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.height + 20 // increase height need to run first
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0, 0)
ctx.rotate(-5*Math.PI/180)
```

Comment: Theres no jquery in your question - so i changed it to javascript

Comment: Question: Are you trying to do animation? If so check out [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Not the animation. Just trying to transform and rotate but transformation and rotation is being done on old canvas height while I have changed it already.

Comment: Can you show the exact problem with a [mcve] - changing the height shouldnt be asynchronous so maybe something else is going wrong. See this example. Canvas height is updated immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/9x3thw4r/

Answer (score 0):

How about `setTimeout` ...

```
ctx.canvas.height = @ctx.canvas.height + 20;
setTimeout(function(){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0, 0);
    setTimeout(function(){
        ctx.rotate(-5*Math.PI/180);
    },100); 
},100);
```

Comment: The `100` values are the delay in milliseconds.